# c++ My timer is unstable Win8.1 VisualStudio

Tags: c++, timer

I do not know how to make stable timer.

Timer did should work every 4ms.
I did use normal event timer in "WndProc()", "CreateTimerQueueTimer()",own timer using "std::chrono::high_resolution_clock" and all timers are unstable. Of course I use one. Sometimes they are calculated at the appointed time or sometimes they are too slow what make my program not smooth. Operations are not complicated is add some integers.

CreateTimerQueueTimer()

```
if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer(&hLogicTimer, hTimerQ, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)Window::LogicThread, NULL, 0, 4, NULL)) return -1;
```

Window::LogicThread() function.

```
void Window::LogicThread()
{
    Window::StartRender = false;
    SC->CalculateActors();
    Window::StartRender = true;
}
```

Own function timer called by new thread.

```
bool Window::LogicThread()
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Time;
    auto start = Time::now();
    const auto constWait = 4000000;

    while (!Window::TerminaterThread)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(constWait - std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(Time::now() - start).count()));
        start = Time::now(); //calculate operation time and sleep thread

        Window::StartRender = false;
        SC->CalculateActors();
        Window::StartRender = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is a Windows timer resolution issue. You may need to set the timer resolution higher. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757633(v=vs.85).aspx 

Sleeping is not guaranteed in any way, so it is not reliable to implement a loop in this way

Comment: Also this - https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/sleep-variation-investigated/

Comment: Yes! Is timer resolution issue.  "timeBeginPeriod(4)" for 4 ms and is work. thank you!!!

Comment: Windows is not a realtime OS.  When your thread gets suspended by the OS scheduler you will never get accurate timing.